# I want to bind id to the ng-model and display name in the input box using uib-typeahead directive

Tags: angularjs

I want to bind id to the ng-model and display name in the input box using uib-typeahead directive. uibtypeahead directive is used from bootstrap.tpls.js file.How can i get this..

```
    <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <title>dynamic form</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.5/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/1.3.3/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js"></script>

    </head>

    <body ng-controller="SearchController">

    <!--  in uib-typeahead specify that property / attribute name which you want to display in drop down 

    in filter service specify an object with which you want to compare 
    for example if you want to compare this object by type then 
    filter : { type : $viewValue }
    <input type="text" ng-model="selected" uib-typeahead="object.name for object in objects | filter: {name:$viewValue} | limitTo:8">
    </body>
    </html>

controller code of ....

var app = angular.module('search', ['ui.bootstrap']);
app.controller('SearchController', function ($scope){                     
    $scope.selected="";

    //  Set your object 
    $scope.objects = [
        {id:1, name : 'Dilip', type :{ title : 'a'}},
        {id:2, name : 'Devendra', type :{ title : 'b'}},
        {id:3, name : 'Jayesh', type :{ title : 'a'}},
        {id:4, name : 'Jekin', type :{ title : 'c'}},
        {id:5, name : 'Gaurang', type :{ title : 'a'}},
        {id:6, name : 'Bhavin', type :{ title : 'e'}},

    ];

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
angular.module('plunker', ['ui.bootstrap']);
function TypeaheadCtrl($scope) {

  $scope.selected = undefined;

  $scope.formatLabel = function(model) {
    for (var i=0; i< $scope.states.length; i++) {
      if (model === $scope.states[i].abbreviation) {
        return $scope.states[i].name;
      }
    }
  }

  $scope.states = [
    {
        name: "Alabama",
        abbreviation: "AL"
    },
    {
        name: "Alaska",
        abbreviation: "AK"
    },
    {
        name: "American Samoa",
        abbreviation: "AS"
    },
    {
        name: "Arizona",
        abbreviation: "AZ"
    },
    {
        name: "Arkansas",
        abbreviation: "AR"
    },
    {
        name: "California",
        abbreviation: "CA"
    },
    {
        name: "Colorado",
        abbreviation: "CO"
    },
    {
        name: "Connecticut",
        abbreviation: "CT"
    },
    {
        name: "Delaware",
        abbreviation: "DE"
    },
    {
        name: "District Of Columbia",
        abbreviation: "DC"
    },
    {
        name: "Federated States Of Micronesia",
        abbreviation: "FM"
    },
    {
        name: "Florida",
        abbreviation: "FL"
    },
    {
        name: "Georgia",
        abbreviation: "GA"
    },
    {
        name: "Guam",
        abbreviation: "GU"
    },
    {
        name: "Hawaii",
        abbreviation: "HI"
    },
    {
        name: "Idaho",
        abbreviation: "ID"
    },
    {
        name: "Illinois",
        abbreviation: "IL"
    },
    {
        name: "Indiana",
        abbreviation: "IN"
    },
    {
        name: "Iowa",
        abbreviation: "IA"
    },
    {
        name: "Kansas",
        abbreviation: "KS"
    },
    {
        name: "Kentucky",
        abbreviation: "KY"
    },
    {
        name: "Louisiana",
        abbreviation: "LA"
    },
    {
        name: "Maine",
        abbreviation: "ME"
    },
    {
        name: "Marshall Islands",
        abbreviation: "MH"
    },
    {
        name: "Maryland",
        abbreviation: "MD"
    },
    {
        name: "Massachusetts",
        abbreviation: "MA"
    },
    {
        name: "Michigan",
        abbreviation: "MI"
    },
    {
        name: "Minnesota",
        abbreviation: "MN"
    },
    {
        name: "Mississippi",
        abbreviation: "MS"
    },
    {
        name: "Missouri",
        abbreviation: "MO"
    },
    {
        name: "Montana",
        abbreviation: "MT"
    },
    {
        name: "Nebraska",
        abbreviation: "NE"
    },
    {
        name: "Nevada",
        abbreviation: "NV"
    },
    {
        name: "New Hampshire",
        abbreviation: "NH"
    },
    {
        name: "New Jersey",
        abbreviation: "NJ"
    },
    {
        name: "New Mexico",
        abbreviation: "NM"
    },
    {
        name: "New York",
        abbreviation: "NY"
    },
    {
        name: "North Carolina",
        abbreviation: "NC"
    },
    {
        name: "North Dakota",
        abbreviation: "ND"
    },
    {
        name: "Northern Mariana Islands",
        abbreviation: "MP"
    },
    {
        name: "Ohio",
        abbreviation: "OH"
    },
    {
        name: "Oklahoma",
        abbreviation: "OK"
    },
    {
        name: "Oregon",
        abbreviation: "OR"
    },
    {
        name: "Palau",
        abbreviation: "PW"
    },
    {
        name: "Pennsylvania",
        abbreviation: "PA"
    },
    {
        name: "Puerto Rico",
        abbreviation: "PR"
    },
    {
        name: "Rhode Island",
        abbreviation: "RI"
    },
    {
        name: "South Carolina",
        abbreviation: "SC"
    },
    {
        name: "South Dakota",
        abbreviation: "SD"
    },
    {
        name: "Tennessee",
        abbreviation: "TN"
    },
    {
        name: "Texas",
        abbreviation: "TX"
    },
    {
        name: "Utah",
        abbreviation: "UT"
    },
    {
        name: "Vermont",
        abbreviation: "VT"
    },
    {
        name: "Virgin Islands",
        abbreviation: "VI"
    },
    {
        name: "Virginia",
        abbreviation: "VA"
    },
    {
        name: "Washington",
        abbreviation: "WA"
    },
    {
        name: "West Virginia",
        abbreviation: "WV"
    },
    {
        name: "Wisconsin",
        abbreviation: "WI"
    },
    {
        name: "Wyoming",
        abbreviation: "WY"
    }
  ];
}


<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="plunker">
  <head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.8/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.6.0.js"></script>
    <script src="example.js"></script>
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.1/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>

<div class='container-fluid' ng-controller="TypeaheadCtrl">
    <pre>Model: {{selected| json}}</pre>
    <input type="text" ng-model="selected" typeahead="state.abbreviation as state.name for state in states | filter:$viewValue | limitTo:8" typeahead-input-formatter="formatLabel($model)">
</div>
  </body>
</html>
```